# Get email on shopware 6 by newsletter's code.(custom action after submit)

Tags: shopware

For get email of user in shopware 6 .I used newsletter's  codes like above

```
        <div class="cms-block footer-newsletter w-100">
            <div class="cms-element-form ">
                <form action="{{ path('frontend.form.newsletter.register.handle') }}"
                      method="post"
                      class="d-flex nws-search py-5"
                      data-form-csrf-handler="true"
                      data-form-validation="true">
                    {{ sw_csrf('frontend.form.newsletter.register.handle') }}
                    {% set formViolations = app.request.get('errors') %}
                    <input type="hidden" name="option" value="subscribe"/>
                    <input type="submit" class="submit--hidden d-none">
                    <input name="email"
                           type="email"
                           id="footerNewsletterMail"
                           placeholder="{{ "account.personalMailPlaceholder"|trans }}{{ "general.required"|trans }}"
                           required="required"
                           value="{{ data.get('email') }}"
                           class="px-3 py-2 py-sm-3 {% if formViolations.getViolations('/email') %} is-invalid{% endif %}"/>

                    <button type="submit" class="px-4 py-2 py-sm-3">JETZT REGISTERIEREN</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
```

It is work.But by default after submit Shopware hide Form then display in panel info.
I don't want the form be hidden .I want to the form info panel display above my form newsletter.How i can do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For solving the issue that i discued.You must define a Controller .
create a controller like above src/Controller/NewsletterController.php

```
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

namespace AK\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Shopware\Core\System\SalesChannel\SalesChannelContext;
use Shopware\Storefront\Controller\StorefrontController;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\Validation\DataBag\RequestDataBag;
use Shopware\Core\Content\ContactForm\ContactFormService;
use Shopware\Core\Content\Newsletter\NewsletterSubscriptionServiceInterface;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\Validation\Exception\ConstraintViolationException;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\Routing\Annotation\RouteScope;
use Shopware\Storefront\Framework\Captcha\Annotation\Captcha;
/**
 * @RouteScope(scopes={"storefront"})
 */
class NewsletterController extends StorefrontController
{
    /**
     * @var NewsletterSubscriptionServiceInterface
     */
    private $newsletterService;

    public function __construct(
        ContactFormService $contactFormService,
        NewsletterSubscriptionServiceInterface $newsletterService

    ) {
        $this->contactFormService = $contactFormService;
        $this->newsletterService = $newsletterService;
    }
    /**
     * @Route("/form/newsletter/custom", name="frontend.form.newsletter.register.handle", methods={"POST"}, defaults={"XmlHttpRequest"=true})
     * @Captcha
     */
    public function handleNewsletter(RequestDataBag $data, SalesChannelContext $context): JsonResponse
    {
        $response = $this->handleSubscribe($data, $context);
        return new JsonResponse($response);
    }
    private function handleSubscribe(RequestDataBag $data, SalesChannelContext $context): array
    {
        try {
            $this->newsletterService->subscribe($data, $context);

            $response[] = [
                'type' => 'success',
                'alert' => $this->renderView('@Storefront/storefront/utilities/alert.html.twig', [
                    'type' => 'info',
                    'list' => [$this->trans('newsletter.subscriptionPersistedInfo')],
                ])
            ];
            $response[] = [
                'type' => 'info',
                'alert' => $this->renderView('@Storefront/storefront/utilities/alert.html.twig', [
                    'type' => 'info',
                    'list' => [$this->trans('newsletter.subscriptionPersistedInfo')],
                ]),
            ];
        } catch (ConstraintViolationException $exception) {
            $errors = [];
            foreach ($exception->getViolations() as $error) {
                $errors[] = $error->getMessage();
            }
            $response[] = [
                'type' => 'danger',
                'alert' => $this->renderView('@Storefront/storefront/utilities/alert.html.twig', [
                    'type' => 'danger',
                    'list' => $errors,
                ]),
            ];
        } catch (\Exception $exception) {
            $response[] = [
                'type' => 'danger',
                'alert' => $this->renderView('@Storefront/storefront/utilities/alert.html.twig', [
                    'type' => 'danger',
                    'list' => [$this->trans('error.message-default')],
                ]),
            ];
        }

        return $response;
    }

}
```

then define your controller in config/servives.xml

```
    <services>
        <service id="AK\Controller\NewsletterController" public="true">
            <argument type="service" id="Shopware\Core\Content\ContactForm\ContactFormService" />
            <argument type="service" id="Shopware\Core\Content\Newsletter\NewsletterSubscriptionService"/>
            <call method="setContainer">
                <argument type="service" id="service_container"/>
            </call>
        </service>

    </services>
</container>
```

and define in config/routs.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<routes xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/routing"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/routing http://symfony.com/schema/routing/routing-1.0.xsd">

    <import resource="../../Controller" type="annotation" />
</routes>
```

Now you can mange response action in your form by controller.